# How to get a immediate previous value from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
      TempTrx                     MissingTrx
DeviceID   TrxID  TrxDate      DeviceID   TrxID
 1101       35    4/3/2020     1101        36   
 1101       35    5/3/2020     1101        37
 1102       19    2/6/2020     1101        38
 1103       42    7/5/2020     1102        36
 1104       19    3/7/2020     1103        56
```

Here the 2 tables must be joined based on DeviceID and I should get all the columns of the TempTrx  for the previous value TrxID of table MissingTrx
i,e for DeviceID =1101  with TrxID=36 of MissingTrx, we have a same DeiviceID in TempTrx  and immediate previous value of TrxID=36 in TempTrx  is Row number 2 i,e: 35 (with recent TrxDate)

```
      ResultTable
DeviceID   TrxID  TrxDate 
1101       35    5/3/2020  o/p for the 1st,2nd,3rd row of MissingTrx
1102       19    2/6/2020  o/p for the 4th row of MissingTrx
1103       42    7/5/2020  o/p for the 5th row
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I don't understand how `missingtrx` is actually needed. This seems like a "simple" [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem for `temptrx` (just pick the row with the most recent trxdate for each device)

Answer (score 0):

Without greater detail and knowing the DB type, surely this is as simple as:

```
select *
from TempTrx t1
join TempTrx t2 on t1.DeviceID = t2.DeviceID - 1
```

If the value of the DeviceID is not sequential, then you would need to change `t2.DeviceID - 1` to accommodate the max value, where the value is less than `t1.DeviceID`, but we would need to know which database you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply`:

```
select tt.*
from (select deviceid, min(trxid) as min_trxid
      from missingtrx
      group by deviceid
     ) m cross apply
     (select top (1) tt.*
      from temptrx tt
      where tt.deviceid = m.deviceid and
            tt.trxid < m.min_trxid
      order by tt.trxid desc
     ) tt;
```